# How do I assign a specific Powerpoint template to open with new PPT session and with Ctrl-N?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, office365

I am trying to reassign the PPT template that opens with Ctrl-N.  The template that currently opens is an old corporate template that I should not use.  I have replaced all the instances of blank.potx with the proper template but Ctrl-N still opens the old file.  I cannot find the old file on my computer searching for it.  I am running Office 365 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the PowerPoint file that you want to be your default theme
2. Save the file as an "Office Theme (*.thmx)" in the following location:
   C:\Users<YOUR NAME>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\Document Themes
3. Go to the Design tab and with one of your slide thumbnails selected drop down the "Themes" list. The file you saved in step #2 should be in the "Custom" section. Right click it and select "Set as Default Theme" ([Animated GIF of these steps)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkKgP.gif).

Pressing CTRL+N should load this new theme by default.